# Configuring Azure AD login with .Net Core 2.2 Web Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c, asp.net-core-2.2

I was given with an URL to use as an Identity provider (using Open connect id protocol), I only have to be able to login using this provider.

The issue I am having is when I try to login, I get this URL in the browser, and after a second it redirects again to my localhost, not been able to login:

https://sitekitdev.b2clogin.com/sitekitdev.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_signuporin/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=6e093bdb-ba93-4c02-83fb-77678f07b14b&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44316%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=636887508645819548.MjQ0ZGQ1YmYtMjNkNC00NDNmLTllNGEtNGRhMDFmODVhZmNlOTQyMmZlODctYTQzYS00N2UyLWJmY2UtMTA1NzI2ODA4Mzc1&state=CfDJ8DRumlJMnSlBuWG5OQqU1yqvjbKErK387uuGadIAJIg-eCgI8wIB58VjX673D3KduNcU0ZwvbW2vgc9QYj6EfW5PXtx38O8JdIG_ioZVPPkNEMipl6dLIhEKpqFy8-wXIPnnHxvBjlB2-FiN6sluOWotTYuYBreowfe927VyOdf1LmN-6avIuTVxB9iexOYE08sR6QksbcTxQM2hrxJ-K6nYWZ3EeBE3TbgUkS4xlGUb68_d162eVwNnuzLzZkBr4eQxAw4VN8BWt8sJsYhjZCZiM98ZwlMCuJCx6PW5D9Tz&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=5.3.0.0

That is what I did when creating a web application:

- In the project template:

  - .Net Core: Asp.net Core 2.2
  - Template: web application (model-view-controller)
  - Change Authentication: I selected individual user account and then Connect to an existing user store in the cloud. After filling all the boxes come out this configuration in the appsettings.json:

    ```
    {
        "AzureAdB2C": {
        "Instance": "https://sitekitdev.b2clogin.com/tfp/",
        "ClientId": "6e093bdb-ba93-4c02-83fb-77678f07b14b",
        "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
        "Domain": "sitekitdev.onmicrosoft.com",
        "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_Signuporin",
        "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "All",
        "EditProfilePolicyId": ""
       },
        "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
           "Default": "Warning"
         }
       },
       "AllowedHosts": "*"
    }
    ```

Then I didn't change nothing alse, so it all the default web page.

The Identity provider endpoint I have to use:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/sitekitdev.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_Signuporin&client_id=6e093bdb-ba93-4c02-83fb-77678f07b14b&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost:44316&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login

Note: the first url, I got in the browser is a bit different than this, in the first one I don't have the first part login.microsoftonline.com

And this is my startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureADB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

I just need to be able to login, and then get the JWT back (I will working configuring this after I am able to see the login page).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the code, you could refer to this [demo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp).

Or you could directly use the url get request to make the user sign in and then return the token.

```
https://tenantname.b2clogin.com/tenantname.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_sample-sign-up-in&client_id=<value>&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.io&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login
```

It will redirects to the login page:

[image]

After the user logging in, it will redirects to your page (here jwt as the example).

[image]

For the openid connect in B2C, you could read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oidc#send-authentication-requests).